# Check for backdoors in PHP scripts

Tags: security, php

My shared host got hacked and I need to check my PHP scripts for backdoors. I'm on a dedicated server now so I can use SSH to run scripts. Are there any good scripts out there to do this task?

Comment: Most of the comments you've received are accurate in that you should not copy compromised code (you didn't specify whether you had) - perhaps you could add that detail?

Answer (score 3):

That is going to be a tough one. I doubt there are scripts that check for Php backdoors or even if it does can weed out all them. It will be best if you can restore using a known good backup.

Change your passwords, including that of DB. Audit the host.

Comment: +1 restore from backup. Without looking over every line of code, you can't be sure that you're clear of exploits.

Answer (score 2):

ClamAV does a pretty good job on this. It doesn't just look for Windows viruses. Depending on your environment something like the following;

Plesk:
freshclam; clamscan -ir /home/httpd/vhosts/*/httpdocs/ | tee ~/possible.phpshells

cPanel:
freshclam; clamscan -ir /home/*/public_html/* | tee ~/possible.phpshells

I use to use the following as until I found that clam did a good job. There are just too many of these to keep up with:

find /home/*/public_html/ -size -200k -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -iE "r57shell|c99shell|g00nshell|EgY_SpIdEr|egy_spider|phpjackal" | uniq -c | sort -u | cut -d":" -f1 | awk '{ print $2 }' | uniq > /root/possible.phpshells

Comment: This will almost certainly miss major vulnerabilities and will only flag known-scripts that have been picked up by clamav.  When there's a compromise, the only guaranteed "safe" thing to do is to restore from a known-good backup.

Comment: Well if he is wanting to find scripts and possibly gain a better understanding how the scripts were uploaded clamav is a good tool to do that before the obvious restore backups.

Answer (score 0):

[maldet](http://www.rfxn.com/projects/linux-malware-detect/) might be good to run.  It may detect things that clamscan doesn't.  For example, it picks up the common 'eval(base64_decode' pattern.

However, I wouldn't trust any code that was from that host.  Restoring from backup is really your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still looking for an answer to this, there is a great free PHP utility that you can run on your server to find base64 encoded strings, and several other common shell strings.

The utility is called [PHP Shell Detector](https://github.com/emposha/PHP-Shell-Detector).

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault. Unfortunately, new users are restricted in posting links. (This restriction is [removed when you get to 10 reputation](http://serverfault.com/privileges/new-user).) I've added a link to the official site for the utility that you referenced.